# Java driver class errors

Tags: java, ms-word, console-application

I have an assignment to make a Tic-Tac-Toe consol game, but I'm a little stuck. The instructor provided the criteria for coding and the driver class to test my TicTacToe.java. If I run the following in the driver class of PlayTicTacToe.java all works great.

```
TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe();
ttt.playGame();
```

But if I use the one provided by the instructor (Below), I get errors and I'm not sure why.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
TicTacToe tictactoe = new TicTacToe('Sally', 'John');
System.out.print(“Would you like to play a game? Y/N: ”);
String play = s.nextLine();
while(play.equals('Y'))
{
tictactoe.playGame();
System.out.print(“Would you like to play a game? Y/N: ”);
play = s.nextLine();
}
TicTacToe tictactoe1 = new TicTacToe(“Sally”, “John”);
TicTacToe tictactoe2 = new TicTacToe(“Sally”, “John”);

// this will show  true
System.out.println( tictactoe1.equals(tictactoe2) );
// this will invoke the toString as shown above
System.out.println( tictactoe1 );
```

The error I get is on the line TicTacToe tictactoe = new TicTacToe('Sally', 'John'); It generates an error 'invalid constant charter' with a red underline on 'Sally'

Any recommendations?

Comment: Single characters are represented with single quotes `'y'`. String use double quotes `"John"`. So replace the single quotes with double ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, single quotes are used to denote characters (not Strings), so you can only have one character inside single quotes.

Change the line to use double quotes:

```
new TicTacToe("Sally", "John");
```

Comment: If I wrap it in quotes then the lines below break such as the line System.out.print(“Would you like to play a game? Y/N: ”); now gives an error of "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens" and the whole System.out.print is now underlined red.

Comment: It looks like you're using smart quotes (a la Microsoft Word). Those won't work — make sure you're using regular quotes.

Comment: Bingo! I should know better than to cut and paste from word to eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

That code has single quotes around the names `('Sally', 'John')`, rather than double quotes `("Sally", "John")`. Although some languages are OK with this (e.g. Python), Java does not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, anything wrapped in a pair of ' denotes a character, whilst " denotes a string.

You are supplying 'Sally' which is wrong, change it to "Sally".

i.e. 'S' is valid but 'Ss' is not.

- your error is probably 'invalid character constant' rather than 'invalid constant character'

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
TicTacToe tictactoe = new TicTacToe('Sally', 'John');
```

to:

```
TicTacToe tictactoe = new TicTacToe("Sally", "John");
```

Presumably the `TicTacToe`  constructor expects a String. `'Sally'` is not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

`sally` is marked with single quotes (`'`). You need too mark it with double quotes (`"`).